# ThreeJS r75 - TypeError: THREE.Animation is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I am using the latest version (to post date) of ThreeJS. I am trying to import a ThreeJS Blender Model with rigged animations. All tutorials I have come across online have mentioned either `THREE.AnimationHandler` or `THREE.Animation`. But I get errors saying no such contructor exists.

When looking through the documentation online I can see them:

[Animation](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Extras.Animation/Animation)

[AnimationHandler](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Extras.Animation/AnimationHandler)

Neither states they are depricated. When looking through the src file I don't see them there either.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

I've faced same problem couple days ago. I found out that new animation system has been implemented in recent releases. This article helped me - [New skinned mesh animation system in three.js](http://yomotsu.net/blog/2015/10/31/three-r73-anim.html). It seems like docs have not been updated yet.

So in my case I needed to import model in `json` and launch animation, code looked like this:

```
 var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader(),
     clock = new THREE.Clock(),
     mixer;

 loader.load('models.json', function (object) {
    // Get object animation
    var sceneAnimationClip = object.animations[0];

    // Create animation mixer and pass object to it
    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);

    // Create animation action and start it
    var sceneAnimation = mixer.clipAction(sceneAnimationClip);
    sceneAnimation.play();

    scene.add(object);

    render()
});

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    // Update animation   
    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    if( mixer ) {
        mixer.update( delta );
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: You need to post some code snippets in the relation to the topic? as the links to resources may come obsolete after a while... Thanks.

Comment: I tried using your sample code to run my animations, however now I get an error of "  can not bind to bones as node does not have a skeleton" repeatedly. Guess its time to head butt the desk and hit every option in the threejs exporter again

Comment: can not bind to bones as node does not have a skeleton

Comment: People who're having the issue as `Can not bind to bones as node does not have a skeleton` can solve it by using `SkinnedMesh`